# How do I disable I2C Designware support when it's not built as a module?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, kernel-modules

I have an Alienware Aurora R7, running Arch Linux. On shutdown, the kernel panics, with something like this in the panic message (omitting timestamps):

```
BUG: Unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at     (null)
IP: i2c_dw_isr+0x3ef/0x6d0
PGD 0 P4D 0
Oops: 0000 [#1] PREEMPT SMP PTI
```

From various sources ([1](http://helloworldproject.blogspot.jp/2016/11/installing-ubuntu-1610-on-alienware.html), [2](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/kernel-panic-at-shutdown/11054/6)), this seems to be related to the `i2c-designware-core` module, and the workaround is blacklisting it. However, with recent kernels (seems to be 4.10 and above), this doesn't seem to be built as a module:

```
# uname -srv                      
Linux 4.15.2-2-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Feb 8 18:54:52 UTC 2018
# zgrep DESIGNWARE /proc/config.gz
CONFIG_I2C_DESIGNWARE_CORE=y
CONFIG_I2C_DESIGNWARE_PLATFORM=y
CONFIG_I2C_DESIGNWARE_SLAVE=y
CONFIG_I2C_DESIGNWARE_PCI=m
CONFIG_I2C_DESIGNWARE_BAYTRAIL=y
CONFIG_SPI_DESIGNWARE=m
CONFIG_SND_DESIGNWARE_I2S=m
CONFIG_SND_DESIGNWARE_PCM=y
```

So I have resorted to making the kernel reboot on panic:

```
# cat /proc/cmdline
root=UUID=e5018f7e-5838-4a47-b146-fc1614673356 rw initrd=/intel-ucode.img initrd=/initramfs-linux.img panic=10 sysrq_always_enabled=1 printk.devkmsg=on
```

(The odd paths in the `/proc/cmdline` are because I boot directly from UEFI, with entries created using `efibootmgr`. The paths are rooted at `/boot`, where my ESP is mounted.)

This seems to be something for touchpads, but I don't have a touchpad and won't get one. What can I do to disable this thing? Do I have to [build a custom kernel](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernels/Arch_Build_System)?

Since `linux-lts` is also newer than 4.10, (4.14, currently), there doesn't seem to be an easy way to install an older kernel either, where blacklisting might presumably work.

---

Using `nolapic` as a kernel parameter solves the shutdown panic problem, but it causes the system to freeze a few minutes after boot, so I can't use it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After reading kernel sources, I found a function we need to blacklist!

Thanks to [Stephen Kitt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/86440/stephen-kitt) for the hint about `initcall_blacklist`.

Add `initcall_blacklist=dw_i2c_init_driver` to the kernel command line. This works for me on kernel 4.15.0.

For anyone else who'll find this answer. You can do it by editing `/etc/default/grub`:

1. Run in the terminal: `sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub`.
2. Append blacklist string to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`:
   `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="… initcall_blacklist=dw_i2c_init_driver"`.
3. Save the file, close the editor.
4. Run in the terminal: `sudo update-grub`.
5. Reboot and test!

Comment: Yep, blacklisting that worked!

Comment: I am using a Dell Aurora  R7 w/ a Nvidia 1070Ti. I am running Kubuntu 18.04.2 on the 4.18.0 kernel and this worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

Adding `initcall_blacklist=i2c_dw_init_master` to the kernel command-line should stop the Designware driver from initialising during boot, and avoid the issue altogether.

See [the kernel parameters](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.txt) for a very brief description of `initcall_blacklist`, and [the thread around the patch](https://lists.gt.net/linux/kernel/1893632) for more useful background information.

Comment: No luck, I still get a kernel panic on `i2c_dw_isr+0x3ef/0x6d0`. Does that mean that function is being pulled by something else, or is the fault in another module?

Comment: It probably means I picked the wrong function to blacklist ;-). Does blacklisting `i2c_dw_probe` work any better? Do you see the blacklist in effect? (It logs a message to the kernel logs saying it’s skipping a function.)

Comment: No luck with `initcall_blacklist=i2c_dw_init_master,i2c_dw_probe` either. `dmesg | grep i2c` does show entries like `[    0.000000] blacklisting initcall i2c_dw_init_master`.

Comment: Do the logs ever mention anything like `initcall i2c_dw_probe blacklisted`?  The `blacklisting` message indicates the boot parameter was used to populate the list, but the `blacklisted` message indicates the call was actually skipped. I could well be barking up the wrong tree here, sorry about that...

Comment: no, only the "blacklisting" message. That is weird - yet another entry point for i2c?

Comment: Presumably a chained entry point from something else where the “one call” `init` function lives (that’s what `initcall_blacklist` filters)...

Comment: Sigh. In the meantime, I have discovered that booting with `systemd.unit=poweroff.target` shuts down fine, so I have added a UEFI boot entry for Linux with that parmeter, and a script that reboots to that boot entry.

Comment: That sounds like a useful answer for other people faced with this issue... I’ll delete mine in a little while.

Comment: Nah, I think keeping it around might be useful - the principle seems to be sound, all we're missing is the correct the init function. Hopefully someone may spot your answer and provide that.

Answer (score 0):

Experimenting with various ways of shutting down, it seems booting Linux to the `poweroff` target using `systemd.unit=poweroff.target` as a kernel parameter shuts down OK.

So, while I wait around for a better solution, I added a boot entry that simply shuts down. This is easy with [GRUB](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB#.22Shutdown.22_menu_entry) (and presumably with other boot loaders), but I couldn't figure out a way to have UEFI itself simply shutdown. And it seems the Alienware's UEFI implementation does not support multiple entries for the same file, so I ended up copying `vmlinuz-linux` and adding an entry for the copy:

```sh
cp /boot/vmlinuz-linux /boot/vmlinuz-shutdown
cp /boot/initramfs-linux.img /boot/initramfs-shutdown.img
kernel_opts="root=UUID=e5018f7e-5838-4a47-b146-fc1614673356 ro initrd=/initramfs-shutdown.img systemd.unit=poweroff.target"
efibootmgr --disk /dev/nvme0n1 --part 1 --create --gpt --label "Shutdown" --loader /vmlinuz-shutdown --unicode "$kernel_opts"
```

Here the disk and partition options are specific to my system. The boot entry created here was numbered `0001`, so an `off` script to give a clean shutdown:

```sh
#! /bin/sh
sudo efibootmgr -n 0001
reboot
```

There probably is a simpler way to have a UEFI shutdown target.