# disable kernel module which is compiled in kernel (not loaded)

Tags: kernel, boot, linux-kernel

My server has two 1-Gbit and two 10-Gbit onboard network cards.

I need to disable the 1-Gbit network cards completely, so that `ifconfig -a` does not show them.

The network cards use different kernel modules. The 10-Gbit use `ixgbe`, and the 1-Gbit use `igb`.

```
01:00.1 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82599ES 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+ Network Connection (rev 01)
Subsystem: Dell Ethernet 10G 4P X520/I350 rNDC
Kernel driver in use: ixgbe

05:00.1 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I350 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 01)
Subsystem: Dell I350 Gigabit Network Connection
Kernel driver in use: igb
```

Both `ixgbe` and `igb` are compiled statically in the kernel (not as a loadable module). I need to disable the module using the kernel boot parameters.

I have tried appending the following to my kernel, but it has no effect:

```
igb.blacklist=yes
igb.enable=0
igb.disable=yes
```

the igb network cards are still showing

How can I disable igb completely ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You should be able to blacklist the `igb` “module”, even when built-in, by blacklisting its initialisation function: add

```
initcall_blacklist=igb_init_module
```

to your kernel’s boot parameters.

See [How do I disable I2C Designware support when it's not built as a module?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/423797/86440) for background information. The general recipe here is to look for the module in the kernel source code, and look for functions which have the `__init` attribute — there should only be one readily identifiable as the main initialisation function (typically referred to in a `module_init` declaration). Blacklist that, and the driver won’t be initialised.

Comment: For those to whom it matters, the `initcall_blacklist` parameter appeared in [Linux 3.16](https://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_3.16#Core).

Comment: is `<modulename>_init_module` the canonical name for each and everything that can be built as a module?

Comment: @Bananguin unfortunately not, there are quite a few called `..._init_module` or `..._module_init` but they don’t all follow those patterns.

Comment: Great answer! I was able to prevent `/dev/ramX` generation at boot, with `brd` built-in, via `initcall_blacklist=brd_init` kernel command-line parameter, taken from: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/block/brd.c
With `brd.rd_nr=0` there is still `/dev/ram0` autogenerated.