# modprobe fuse doesn't seem to load module

Tags: kernel-modules, fuse, modprobe

I'm trying to load the `fuse` kernel module but for some reason it seems like it's not getting loaded. But I also don't get any error message. Can someone explain to me what's going on?

```bash
root@my-host:~# modprobe fuse
root@my-host:~# echo $?
0
root@my-host:~# lsmod | grep fuse 
root@my-host:~# modinfo fuse
modinfo: ERROR: Module fuse not found.
root@my-host:~# ls /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/fs/fuse/
cuse.ko
root@my-host:~#
```

I'm on a cloud VM:

```
root@my-host:~# uname -r
4.15.0-213-generic
root@my-host:~# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

I also rebooted the host before I ran these commands to make sure the correct kernel is running.

---

EDIT: In response to the comments I ran these commands:

```
root@my-host:~# grep fuse /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/modules.builtin
kernel/fs/fuse/fuse.ko
root@my-host:~# systemd-detect-virt
kvm
```

Comment: I also noticed that this is the same for my desktop Ubuntu. Probably because it uses a similar kernel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, if loading a module succeeds but that module doesn’t appear in `lsmod`’s output, it’s because the module is built-in — *i.e.* it’s part of the main kernel image and is always available¹.

To check whether that’s the case, look in `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/modules.builtin`:

```
grep fuse /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/modules.builtin
```

If this shows a kernel module path matching the module you expect, it means the corresponding “module” is built-in.

---

¹ Many built-in modules can still be disabled if necessary, see [disable kernel module which is compiled in kernel (not loaded)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/468024/86440).